# Installing Gimp on Ubuntu problems

Tags: gimp

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my old PC. I have tried to install GIMP, but without any success. I used

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

The process ran for a while, but I got a number of errors and part of the output was

> "The repository “cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS *Focal Fossa* - Release amd64 (20200 423) focal release” does not have a release file".
>   N: "Updating from such a repository can’t be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default".
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   E: The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnomebaker/stable/ubuntu focal release does not have a release file.

If anyone has any suggestions, I should be very grateful.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are trying to add the ppa and install that way? For me, the latest version (2.10.18) is available in the Ubuntu Software and I think can also be installed with `sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: As new as v20.04 is, the PPA probably hasn't updated its files yet. You can always try flatpak or snap (both on v2.10.18).

Comment: @codlord -  we posted at the exact same time! You're absolutely right - use the version already built for v20.04.

Comment: Suggestion: Distrust any online instructions (and author) that blindly instructs you to add a PPA. Lots of good tutorials out there,,,and lots of lousy tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a problem with the PPA (which used to be very trustable...), it hasn't been updated since Gimp 2.10.14 last fall (current version is 2.10.18), so it doesn't support 20.04 yet.

2) The official solution (from Gimp development) to get the latest Gimp on Ubuntu is to use a [flatpak version](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP).

3) IIRC the Gimp that you get with `apt install` in 20.04 is a "snap" package.

4) There are also 'AppImage' versions of Gimp.

If you intent to use a rather plain Gimp, snap, flatpak and appimage will do the job, but they have restrictions: for instance the 'snap' version can only edit files under your home directory, while the flatpak version has its own "recent files" list, so you cannot easily upload a file your just edited, or edit a file you just downloaded. Adding compiled plugins that have their own dependencies may also prove difficult.

The better solution is to compile your own, which isn't that difficult, it is documented [here](https://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Building). These instructions aren't 100% foolproof (there are some missing dependencies, quite easy to spot). Depending on the GIT branch/tag you use, you have the current 2.10.18, the fixes to be applied toward 2.10.20 (as 2.10 branch), or the future Gimp 3.0 WIP (as the master branch).

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.